# How do I properly create this Ruby method in my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I submit a form, it's being submitted with an attachment. I'm trying to create a method that finds out if the attachment is an image or video and then save it as such because there is a column for videos and a column for images.

Here's the code from my model:

```
class Medium < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mediumable, :polymorphic => true

  has_attached_file :image, :url => "/system/:class/:image/:id/:style/:filename", :styles => { :thumbnail => '174X174>', :large => '470' }

  attr_accessible :attachment

  validates :attachment, :presence => true

  def attachment
    debugger
    image || video
  end

  def attachment=(value)
    value.content_type.include? "image" ? image = value : video = value
  end
end
```

This is the error I get when I try to submit anything:

```
TypeError (can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String):
  app/models/medium.rb:17:in `include?'
  app/models/medium.rb:17:in `attachment='
  app/controllers/media_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Comment: What is the value of `value` in your `#attachment=()` method? Put a `raise value.inspect` statement at the top of the method and try to upload a file and tell us what's the output.

Comment: His value should be the ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object, which it seems like he is attempting to store in a string "column" on his database…

Comment: It was a simple syntax error

    value.content_type.include? "image" ? image = value : video = value

is supposed to be:

     value.content_type.include?("image") ? image = value : video = value